# What's the simplest technique for initializing a complex record type?

Tags: f#

What's the simplest technique for initializing a complex record type?

I want to do the following:

```
type BenefitsOverviewViewModel() =

    member val Overview:BenefitsOverview = null with get,set
```

Of course, null is not valid for initializing this property.

However, I plan on initializing this property with an external data source later.

Are there any options for initializing a complex record without having to identify and assign a value for each of its members?

Comment: I passed a value into the types constructor and used it for initialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe. Nuff said. Or?

You want to say something like "maybe its initialized" or "maybe its not"...

So maybe you got Some, or maybe you got None. The Option is yours.

Which is better than initializing it with something. Or nothing.

If it is initialized with something, how are you going to keep the something from nothing, if nothing is also something?

And since it cant be modified anyway why initialize something at all when it in fact is nothing?

And each change, from something, or nothing, will recreate everything. And you might not even know if something, or Just nothing, has changed.

And this is the simple way?

I did say the Option is yours?

Otherwise you can possibly do "better" modelling than that again. And use a DU like:

```
type MyRecordsAre = 
 | Initialized of MyRecords 
 | NotInitializedYet
```

And then you might even do stuff like:

```
type MyRecordsAre = 
 | Initialized of MyRecords 
 | NotInitializedYet
 | InitializedButNotVerified of MyRecords
 | ReadFromOracleDbAndVerfiedAndReadyForFurtherHandling of MyRecords
 | ReadFromFileButNotYetValidated of MyRecords
 | FuckenDoNotTouchThisAnymore of MyRecords
```

And suddenly you are close to also modell somewhat more, kind of like a state and stuff...

You are then able to see that it is nothing, or something, and even see what has happened or what is possible to happen. Yepp, maybe even decide on what to do next with something. Unless its nothing. And actually also if it is nothing. Or in fact let it degrade from something to nothing. Or even not let anyone do something, no matter if it is nothing or something. If you want that Option.

And the Option is still yours.

Now run along and do as you have been told earlier. Read more. Especially https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/

Maybe. Just then ...

Ok, I will go and get assimilated and be taken upstairs again... Or? ;-)

https://vimeo.com/113588389#t=3m

Comment: Thanks. I ended up passing a value into the types constructor. I then initialized my property with that value. That resolved my issue.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to use the record type between being created and being initialized by the external source?

As @Helge might say, Maybe is Just an Option - although their answer is good, there are other ways.

One of them is decomposing the complex record type into smaller ones, and putting them together as you go, when you have the data. Every individual step would be relatively small, but you will end up with multiple objects. On the other hand this approach doesn't allow you represent an incorrect/not fully initialized state of the single type.

Another might be creating a "constructor function" that will take the missing value as a parameter and close over the rest to create the large record. Return this function so that you can later call it with the rest of the data to produce the fully initialized value.